# CSS max-height not working when trying to preserve aspect ratio using padding-bottom trick

Tags: html, css

I can demonstrate my issue with this simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .embedContainer{
            padding-bottom: calc((1200 / 1200) * 100%);
            position: relative;
            max-height: 60vh;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .embedContainer iframe {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="embedContainer">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/8dXNoC4UviY?rel=0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" allowtransparency="true" allow="clipboard-write; encrypted-media; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" loading="lazy"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice the `calc((1200 / 1200) * 100%)`. Here, `1200` numerator is the actual height of the video and `1200` denominator is the actual width of the video. In this case, the video's actual resolution is a square of `1200x1200`.

The `padding-bottom` trick is to ensure aspect ratio of the video is maintained in most cases (wider videos). However, when a video is too tall, I don't want it to exceed the `max-height` of 60vh.

However, in the above example, `max-height: 60vh;` doesn't seem to have any effect at all. I thought that maybe `padding-bottom` might be preventing it from working, so I set `box-sizing: border-box; overflow: hidden;` but that didn't have any effect.

Why's `max-height` not working? How can I get it to work to ensure the `embedContainer` doesn't exceed a certain height?

Comment: _"Why's max-height not working?"_ - it is working perfectly fine, in that the height of your element does not exceed the 60vh you specified. Its height is, in fact, still _zero_ - because that's the basic principle behind the padding-bottom-hack in the first place: That the container element _does_ have zero height, and is actually spanned up by nothing but the padding-bottom. // [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) exists, and has good browser support.

Comment: @CBroe didn't know about the `aspect-ratio`. That solved the issue. If you post that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why's max-height not working?

It is working perfectly fine, in that the height of your element does not exceed the 60vh you specified. Its height is, in fact, still zero - because that's the basic principle behind the padding-bottom-hack in the first place: That the container element does have zero height, and is actually spanned up by nothing but the padding-bottom.
So you can't specify a max-height here, to get the desired outcome.

But the [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) property exists, and has good browser support.